# Identify edges that increase maximum flow in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have to find the maximum flow of a graph and then identify the edges such that if their capacity is increased, the maximum flow of the graph increases.

I have successfully found the maximum flow by applying a Relabel-To-Front algorithm but can't seem to think of a way to find out what edges have the potential to increase the maximum flow.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem

Comment: @user3386109 how is that helpful?

Comment: The edges that may increase the maximum flow are the edges that form the min-cut. This is a consequence of the min-cut/max-flow theorem. But beware that the min-cut might not be unique, so such edges might actually not exist (you could find instances of graph where increasing the capacity of any edge does not increase the max flow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find such edges by solving the dual problem of the max-flow problem: the [min-cut problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut).
A consequence of the [max-flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) is that the edges forming a min-cut on your graph are actually the saturated edges in a max-flow.
So if there are edges that may increase the max-flow in a graph, they are part of a min-cut.
But there is no guarantee that there exists an edge in your graph such that increasing the flow of this edge would lead to a greater flow. In some cases, you would need to increase the capacity of all edges of the graph in order to increase the max-flow.

A way to test that is to compute the min-cut, then try and increase the capacity on one or several edges of this min-cut, and recompute the flow to compare to its previous value.

Comment: Thank you! I did some digging and found that a good idea of going about it was to perform a BFS starting on the sink and disregarding edges that are saturated.